# Trigger 'touchstart' does not work inside of setTimeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, mobile, settimeout

I want to trigger focus on an input on mobile inside of a setTimeout function. This works fine:

```
$('input').on('touchstart', function(){
    $(this).focus();
});
$('input').trigger('touchstart');
```

However, this does not work:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $('input').on('touchstart', function(){
        $(this).focus();
    });
    $('input').trigger('touchstart');
},200);
```

The placeholder disappears as if the input were focused, but the keyboard and the cursor do not appear. I have no idea why. Is there any way to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

Separate timeout from setting the listener:

```
// It's ok to listen
$('input').on('touchstart', function(){
        $(this).focus();
    });

// Trigger only when you want it
setTimeout(function(){
    $('input').trigger('touchstart');
},200);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you need a timeout but this seems to work.

```js
$('input').on('touchstart', function() {
  $(this).focus();
});
setTimeout(function() {
  $('input').trigger('touchstart');
}, 200);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" placeholder="foo"></input>
```